# Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I want to build apk file, but i cant, because i have 2 errors. I tried lots of solutions, for example multiDexEnabled true or something like that, but didnt work.. Please help:)

Errors:

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sgtt.celtkituzes_0_1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.backendless:backendless:3.0.20.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't ever be using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` as that includes every Google Play services library - only use the [APIs you need](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

This should reduce your method count enough to fit under the 64K limit.

Comment: Thank you this fast and satisfied answer :)